# Unity MiniMap not Rendering on Phone

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rendering

I'm currently doing a little 2D game where you can walk around and interact with things. Unfortunately I encountered a problem. When I made the minimap and tested it, everything went smoothly.
[Here i tested it on pc in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q26Pe.png)
But when i build it to my phone and tested it there i just got this black square instead of my minimap.
[On my Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o9cs.jpg)
I searched online in stckoverflow and in Unity docs but didn´t find anything.
Here the settings from my cameras

[My main camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alDWm.png)

[My MiniMap Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zraNV.png)

And the Settings from the
[Render Texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6duAo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the broblem. I just had to do the depth buffer to "at least 24 bits depth" on render texture